# Spacing in Dirac's ket vector

Tags: spacing

I have defined myself a `\ket` which does `\left| #1 \right\rangle`. For a state with two numbers, say `n` and `m`, one writes, on paper, `|a b>`. What kind of distance should I use to separate those numbers? `\,` or more?

Comment: Have you seen the [`braket`](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) package? (Not answering your question, just as an apropos.)